# How to tell if there is a missing item in request.REQUEST in Django

Tags: python, django

I have five keys that I want to check are in request.REQUEST.  So I want to make sure first_name, last_name, age, gender, and location are all in request.REQUEST.  Then if one or more are not there, I want to tell the which attributes are missing.

Is there a way to do this without using a bunch of if statements?

Comment: Yes. Use [forms](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/)

Answer (score 1):

Create a set of the keys that you expect, and a set of the keys that were returned, and intersect them:

```
expected = set(['first_name', 'last_name', 'age'])
got = set(request.REQUEST.keys())

if expected.issubset(got):
    # Request contained everything you expected
    # Bonus points: check if field was present but empty
    for field in got:
        if request.REQUEST[field].strip() == "":
            # Field was present but empty
else:
    # Some things were different
    print expected.difference(got)
```

You can also use different methods on `expected` at the very beginning. Here, I've checked that `expected` is a subset of `got`, so `got` could contain more than was expected. If you want to check they're exactly the same, change it to:

```
if len(expected.difference(got)) == 0:
```

(ie. If there are zero differences between the two).

But really, you should use [Django's built in Forms](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/). It's a lot nicer to do things like this.

Answer (score 0):

```
missing_keys = []
for i in ('item1', 'item2', 'item3'):
  if i not in request.REQUEST:
    missing_keys.append(i)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import sets
missing = sets.Set(request.REQUEST.keys()).difference(['first_name', 'last_name', ...])
```

Update, using the builtin set:

`set(request.REQUEST.keys()).difference(['first_name', 'last_name', ...])`

Comment: Why even to use sets module, but not the builtin set type? The module is deprecated btw